# Fetch GET request not getting to API on Android Syntax Error: JSON Parse Error unexpected EOF parse@[native code]

Tags: android, get, react-native, expo, fetch-api

I am trying to use the Fetch API to process and GET req. to a public AWS API Gateway (with no authorization required).

The following code works on flawlessly on IOS (iPhone and Ipad) but not Android:

```
fetchData= async() =>{
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const AAA = navigation.getParam('AAA',);
  const route= '/info'

  const response = await fetch(`${config.url}${route}?AAA=%${AAA}%`,
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': config.key
    }
  });
  const setdata = await response.json();
  this.setState({data: setdata});
}
```

I am in an Expo Managed app currently and testing through Expo Cli on a device.
I am using Expo SDK 34.
Trying to avoid adding the AWS Amplify library as its so big for just this need.
If I put the response into Console.warn(response) I get the error:

Syntax Error: JSON Parse Error unexpected EOF parse@[native code]

The CloudWatch Metrics on AWS doesn't even show the API is called/reached.

All I have been able to find is:

- POST requests that use okHttp append a Content-Type header that causes
  issues (doesn't seem to be a problem with a GET request though)
- Fetch request made through Android to a 'https' URL vs 'https' fail (but my API is 'https')
- Added a SSL cert to my API, but it didn't make a difference
- I tried to recreate this in a Snack, but on the Android Emulator in the Snack it seems to work? But still not on a device.

Comment: Can you get and look at string text result replace json to :  const set= await response.text();
 and post result in answer?

Comment: I tried to put the response to text and got something like:

[]

I think it is just an empty array, which is what my initial state of data is:

state= {
data: [],
}

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/network/

take a reference from this and then implement

Comment: I have read the docs and thought I was following them, could you point to where my code isn’t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using wildcards (%) in my MySql syntax I was passing in the URL string. IOS handled that find, Android did not. Adjusting the backend to process the wildcards made the difference, apparently you cannot use Fetch API on android if you are passing a '%' in the URL string.